# My @font-face not working at all

Tags: css, font-face

I'm using a separate stylesheet to load my @font-family, but when I test locally it's not working.

```
font-face {
    font-family: HelvNeueBold;
    src: url(HelvNeueBold.otf);
}
```

The `otf` files are in the same folder my stylesheet is stored:

```
<link href='css/lpfonts.css' rel="stylesheet" >
```

Any ideas why it would be failing?

Thanks

Comment: Here is the directory for the style sheet, link href='css/lpfonts.css' rel="stylesheet"

Comment: I've tried placing the url in apostrophies, but it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue Bold';
    src: url('HelvNeueBold.otf');
}
```

Comment: Still fails when using that syntax.

Comment: So the otf file is in the css folder? Shouldn't the path be url('css/HelvNeueBold.otf')? What browser are you testing with?

Comment: Yes, all the otf files are in the same folder as the CSS requesting it. I tried using 'css/HelvNeueBold.otf') and still failed. I'm testing in Firefox.